# How to do circle array with custom vertices with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hi any idea to do mesh like on picture?

[image: octagon with even insets]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be easy using mesh primitives:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 I cannot believe I tried to do this with complicated math for hours….‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks